# C++ Template is sending a "false argument" a bad practice?

Tags: c++, templates

std::stoi is throwing some errors in specific cases. I don't want to use try/catch block, so I googled a little bit about char convertion and saw that `std::from_chars` was doing exactly what I wanted, without those try/catch block.

Obviously, using `std::from_chars` directly works pretty well, but I don't like the syntax. So I started writing my own `ToInt()`, `ToFloat()`, etc. And was like : "ok, that sounds stupid, let's use template".

Here I am :

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <charconv>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T ToNumber(const char* str, T varType)
{
    if (!str)
        return 0;
    T var = 0;
    std::from_chars(str, str + strlen(str), var);
    return var;
}

int main()
{
    std::string t = "123.5";

    auto a = ToNumber(t.c_str(), (int)0); // a will be an int (123)
    float b = ToNumber(t.c_str(), (int)0); // b will store the value as int (123)
    auto c = ToNumber(t.c_str(), (float)0); // c will be a float (123.5)

    std::cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

It actually works, that is not the problem. But I was wondering... Is it a good practice to send a "false argument" (`T varType`) in order to get the cast done and enable `auto` ?

If not, what is the clever way to write such a function ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The question would be better if you explained *why* you decided to use an ignored parameter. What is the benefit? What issue did it solve? You might then ask yourself if you want your question to focus on your solution to that issue or on that issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not checking the return value of `std::from_chars` for failure, eg:

```cpp
auto [p, ec] = std::from_chars(str, str + strlen(str), var);
if (ec != std::errc()) {
    ...
}
```

That said, another way to deal with the template argument `T` without using a type-casted input parameter is to simply specify the desired type explicitly at the call site instead, eg:

```cpp
template <typename T>
T ToNumber(const char* str)
{
    if (!str)
        return T{};
    T var{};
    auto [p, ec] = std::from_chars(str, str + strlen(str), var);
    if (ec != std::errc())
        return T{};
    return var;
}

auto a = ToNumber<int>(t.c_str());
float b = ToNumber<int>(t.c_str());
auto c = ToNumber<float>(t.c_str());
```

Otherwise, you can use template argument deduction via a reference output parameter (just like `std::from_chars()` does), eg:

```cpp
template <typename T>
bool ToNumber(const char* str, T &var)
{
    if (!str)
        return false;
    auto [p, ec] = std::from_chars(str, str + strlen(str), var);
    return (ec == std::errc());
}

int a;
ToNumber(t.c_str(), a);

int tmp;
ToNumber(t.c_str(), tmp);
float b = tmp;

float c;
ToNumber(t.c_str(), c);
```

Comment: Worth noting that if you do this, you no longer use the argument at all and if you remove it you can just write `ToNumber<int>(t.c_str())`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and yep, as @MichaelAnderson stated, the (type)0 was just here to cast T. I didn't know about the Func<Type>() syntax so I guess it is a bad practice and should be avoided, thank you !